# full disk encryption interface on boot

Tags: login, customization, plymouth, desktop-background, interface

Is there a way to customize the full disk encryption interface on boot? I want a different background or a blank screen showing instead of this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgRlo.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package responsible for this screen called Plymouth. Following ways possible, from simple to hard:

### Use another precreated Plymouth theme

There are plenty themes around, some in Ubuntu distribution:

- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=plymouth-theme

And even more in Internet:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=Plymouth+Themes

Install it and select with the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

### Use GUI tool to create your own theme

- Plymouth Manager ( install it from Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/plymouth-manager )

### Manually create theme or redesign existing

Plymouth themes stored at `/lib/plymouth/themes/`. Copy any existing theme directory (eg. `ubuntu-logo`) as your theme template (eg. to your home directory), renaming directory to "mytheme" or name you like. Modify theme information file (ends with `.plymouth` ), color script (ends with `.script` ), graphic file, etc. the way you like.

Copy your theme to the right place:

```
sudo cp -R ~/mytheme /lib/plymouth/themes/
```

Install your new theme:

```
do update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/mytheme/mytheme.plymouth 100
```

Select your theme as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

There's good article describing the process:

- http://www.khattam.info/howto-change-ubuntu-pinkpurple-plymouth-boot-screen-to-any-color-you-like-2010-11-09.html

Comment: thanks got it, can I change the hotkeys ESC, ARROWUP and F1 to change between logo or text mode?

Comment: I can't see a way to do it without changing source code of plymouth binary so far. Possible direction to look - use /etc/boottime.kmap.gz file to change boottime key mapping to required. But if you just need to remove all boottime output from  screen the easy way is to switch to text mode theme ( see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth#Toggling_to_Traditional_Text-based_Boot ) and change theme colors to black on black.